# Turing machine that does not accept - how can we know it?

Tags: turing-machines

Suppose i have a TM M that **accepts** a language L. If i give it an input word **w** and want to know whether it accepts or loops forever - can i state without explaining what i do if M does NOT accept w ?

I mean - the phrase "if M does not accept w" assumes that each algorithm is implicitly able to identify an infinite loop.

I see it a lot in reducibility problems where M is an inner TM within an algorithm that uses M's acceptances as well as M's **non-acceptance** and i never saw an explanation how the outer algorithm is able to know that M did **not accept**. It is just said - "if M accept.... else....", how can the algorithm detect the "else" part ? In case of infinite loop, how is it detected ?

Thanks

Comment: Probably a better fit for https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you give a specific example? You're right that in general, there's no way to tell that a Turing machine will *not* accept a particular input because of the possibility of looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in general, not detect algorithmically that a TM does not stop on a given input.

For the "if M accept.... else...." problems, one possibility is that the else part always leads to non-acceptance. In that case it does not matter whether the inner TM loops or not. If it does, the outer one will also loop and not accept. Therefore the else part does not need to be executed.

Another possible case is that you only look at recursive/decidable languages in the inner TM. Then you will always get an answer.